# JSF Validation error: Correct values are lost

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

I am using JSF Mojarra 2.1.7 with Spring Web Flow 2.3.0.I am really stuck with this strange problem . I am really wondering if I am missing something is really simple or it is really like this in JSF.

If I put a input field on a form and give it a **required** attribute and fill a few fields correctly and leave one field empty , JSF gives me a nice validation error. But I left one field empty and even other ones were correcly filled they were also lost.

For instance on the form I have 2 fields **name** and **password**. Both of them contains *required* attribute of the JSF. I entered "My name" as value for the name field and I didn't enter any value for the password field. JSF gave me an error about password field and correct value I entered for the name field "My name" is also empty now.

Now I am wondering is this default behaviour ? How can I solve this problem. If it is normal behaviour I will be really surprized because this is a really basic requirement I think.

Comment: No, this is not the default behaviour.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing an SSCCE. I've never experienced this myself before, so I can't answer from experience. My first feeling would say: blame Spring. But that can be because I've never used it.

Comment: We are blaming Spring right now :) I will try to give a SSCCE. I have been almost reading all of your articles for days to solve this problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I upgraded to newly released Spring Web Flow 2.3.1 problem resolved.

Comment: Wow. I wonder what exactly SWF is all doing with JSF lifecycle.

Comment: unhopefully if you use the latest JFS-2.1.22 it happens again with spring-webflow 2.3.1.RELEASE or 2.3.2.RELEASE. With JSF 2.1.21, all is normal.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue after going from 2.1.21 to 2.1.22. Am hoping the next release will fix the issue as it looks like there are some performance improvements introduced with 2.1.22

Answer (score 0):

Same behaviour with JSF version 2.1.24 with spring EL resolver turned off. But the cause can be due to spring RequestContextListener or DelegatingFilterProxy. We only use spring security.

Update: resolved after JSF update. There is probably several related issues with jsf. One of issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3033